# Sonarqube concern about PMD & Maven plugins

Tags: maven, plugins, sonarqube, pmd

I am using Sonarqube 10.1 and I have to move to 10.2, however I have a concern - This article https://community.sonarsource.com/t/pmd-plugin-causes-sonar-maven-to-fail-with-sonarqube-10-2/99605 found in the forums is about a problem encountered on 10.2 with PMD & Maven.
And AFAIK PMD will no longer be supported from 10.2 onwards. Source :
https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/instance-administration/plugin-version-matrix/

PMD and Maven plugin is something that I really need in my project. So what should I do? What are my options here? Stay forever on Pre-10.0 Sonarqube system forever? That doesn't seem right?

Best regards!

Contacted Sonarsource to ask them but they've told me that this is a third party plugin so they can't promise anything.

Comment: The question is why do you use SonarQube if you use PMD vice versa.. I would suggest to use SonarQube only and that's it.. And what does that mean: `that I really need in my project`... ?

Answer (score 0):

Sonarqube 10.2 does not work with the pmd plugin at the moment. If i tried it with Sonarqube Enterprise Edition.

cheers